# Image in IE11 returned 200 with image data but did not show image. Click show picture, and then it shows

Tags: image, sharepoint

**Context (Not sure if relevant)**:

I have an authentication process with Sharepoint through an iframe... Once that authentication occurs, the image src is reloaded to show the image.

**The issue**:

If i look in fiddler, I can see the entire authentication process occur... and at the end, i see the image load and return a 200. This request seems to have the image data in it.

In IE 11, the image continued to show as broken. However, i then clicked "show picture" in the context menu, and the image then appeared correctly.

Here is the image request that displayed 200 but didn't show:

> **HTTP/1.1 200 OK**
>   **Cache-Control:** private, max-age=86400
>   **Content-Length:** 11219
>   **Content-Type:** image/jpeg
>   **ETag:** "..."
>   **Server:** Microsoft-IIS/8.5
>   **Set-Cookie:** rtFa=..; domain=sharepoint.com; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
>   **Set-Cookie:** FedAuth=..; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
>   **X-SharePointHealthScore:** 0
>   **Content-Disposition:** attachment; filename=.._com_LThumb.jpg
>   **X-AspNet-Version:** 4.0.30319
>   **SPRequestGuid:** ..
>   **request-id:** .. 
>   **Strict-Transport-Security:** max-age=31536000
>   **X-FRAME-OPTIONS:** SAMEORIGIN
>   **X-Powered-By:** ASP.NET
>   **MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices:** 16.0.0.6001
>   **X-Content-Type-Options:** nosniff
>   **X-MS-InvokeApp:** 1; RequireReadOnly
>   **P3P:** CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
>   **Date:** Tue, 13 Dec 2016 11:29:02 GMT

The html of image:

```
<img width="65" height="65" id="user-profile-picture" onerror="SPImageLoader.ImageErrored(this)" alt="" src="https://something.com/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=L&amp;url=https://something.sharepoint.com/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/something_com_LThumb.jpg" load-when-authenticated="">
```

**Question:**

Can you tell me what kind of things can happen to make this occur? What might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff header. IE11 sees that the image content-type is different.

Answer (score -1):

Just include

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<![endif]-->
```